# Bar Chart: Add GEOM_TEXT in R while only have X mapping

Tags: r, bar-chart, geom-text

I am trying to analyze the values of online sales and wanted to determine the exact number of times that the event type occur (view the product, add product to cart, and purchase the product) for the entire data >> this events are in the same column "event_type"

I am trying to add geom_text into the bar chart but R ask me for the Y aesthetics and this one was generated automatically by "count" of times that the event type occured.

```
ggplot(data=online_sales_02)+
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=factor(event_type), fill=factor(event_type), stat="count")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  scale_fill_discrete(name='Event Type')+
  labs(x="Type of Event", y="Count", title="Percentage of the Total Numbers of Events Types", subtitle="Online Sales Analysis",
       caption="September 2020 to February 2021 data")+
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..), stat="count", position=position_stack())
```

Later I planned to mutate this figures into percentage.

Can someone please explain me how to add geom_text into bar chart without Y?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it, with the `mtcars` data...

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_bar() +
    geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)))
```

[image]